# lamejs is not outputting any audible sound

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lame

I'm trying to encode my audio buffer into mp3, but, when I download the blob and try to play it I don't hear anything (pkg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lamejs )

```
const encodeAudioBufferLame = ({ channels }) => {
  const chnls = 1; // 1 for mono or 2 for stereo
  const sampleRate = 44100; // 44.1khz (normal mp3 samplerate)
  const kbps = 128; // encode 128kbps mp3
  const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(chnl, sr, kbps);
  const mp3Data = [];

  const samples = new Int16Array(channels); // one second of silence (get your data from the source you have)

  const sampleBlockSize = 1152; // can be anything but make it a multiple of 576 to make encoders life easier

  for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {
    const sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);

    const mp3buf = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
    if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
      mp3Data.push(mp3buf);
    }
  }

  const mp3buf = mp3encoder.flush(); // finish writing mp3

  if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
    mp3Data.push(new Int8Array(mp3buf));
  }

  const blob = new Blob(mp3Data, { type: 'audio/mp3' });

  return blob;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lamejs exports mp3 compressed audio file with no sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901633/lamejs-exports-mp3-compressed-audio-file-with-no-sound)